# Oracle Performance issues(manual vs procedure)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a "insert into tableA select from TableB" statement. If i run the statement manually it takes less than 2 sec's. How ever if i have the same statement in a procedure/package, it takes more than 30 mins. Am i missing any thing?

I also tried executing the select only, it also returns data in 2 secs.(only 70k rows). Any suggestions are much appreciated.Thank you in adavance.

Comment: Do you get different plans when you run the query manually vs. when it is run in the procedure?  Is your actual SQL statement more complicated than this?  Are there predicates, for example?  Are you using bind variables in the procedure vs. hard-coded parameters in the procedure?

Comment: @JC ...I dont have access to check the plan. Yes the procedure has variables, when running manually, i hard code the variable value.

Comment: Can you get the actual plan(s)?  My first guess is that you're getting a different plan because of bind variable peeking in the stored procedure.  Are there histograms on the columns that are part o fyour predicate(s)?  Is the data in those columns skewed?

Comment: Does 'more than 30 minutes' mean it completed in that time, or did you kill it before it finished? My first guess is that you ran the insert manually in one session, then ran the procedure version in a different session and it's blocked because you haven't rolled back the first one. At least if the table you are inserting into has a primary key or unique index.

Comment: Is `INSERT INTO TABLE_A SELECT FROM TABLE_B` a simplification of the actual SQL? In particular, does the SELECT have a WHERE clause associated with it?

Comment: @JC - I did gave different id's for manual run vs procedure. so i ensure there is no locking.

Comment: @BJ - Yes thats a simpler version, the select has joins and where conditions

Comment: I updated table statictics and procedure is alos quicker now...Thanks all